# Debian SSH disabled password logins but can still login

Tags: ssh, debian

I have setup a debian install on a VPS and have successfully implemented key based logins to increase security.

Now I am trying to disable password based logins entirely using the guide found at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-debian-8

I have modified my /etc/ssh/sshd_config file to set the following...

```
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitRootLogin no
UsePAM no
```

But on rebooting my server I am still able to login using a username and password.

Anyone have any ideas?

**UPDATE**
Added PasswordAuthentication no to ssh config, after rebooting it is still letting me login with a password though

** UPDATE **
Removed commenting # from the beginning of the line...

```
#PasswordAuthentication no
```

All working now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To disable Password authentication for SSH, you need to set one more value in your /etc/ssh/sshd_config

`PasswordAuthentication no`

Set that, restart SSH and try again

Comment: Thanks for that, what an obvious one to miss!  I have added this now though and after a reboot I am still able to login with a username and password.  I have updated the OP to reflect this

Comment: Glad you figured it out, it's often something simple like a commented line